# How to serve the Django static files using ShimmerCat?

Tags: django, http2, shimmercat

I have been testing a bit the HTTP2 server [ShimmerCat](https://www.shimmercat.com/), and I have set up a reverse proxy on it to use Django. All this has worked like a charm so far, but I have a doubt. Right now I'm serving the Django static files using the approach that `Django` has to serve them in development, which means that I have left the settings `DEBUG=True`, but as we all know it is not a good practice for production. Is there a way I can use to serve the `Django` static files with `ShimmerCat` itself?

Here it is the `ShimmerCat` config file:

`devlove.yaml`:

```
    ---
    shimmercat-devlove:
        domains:
            www.mysite.com:
                root-dir: site
                consultant: 8000
                cache-key: xxxxxxxxxxx
            api.mysite.com:
                port: 8000
```

Could I use a `subdomain` e.g `static.mysite.com` to do that? Could the config below be a good solution?

`devlove.yaml`:

```
    ---
    shimmercat-devlove:
        domains:
            www.mysite.com:
                root-dir: site
                consultant: 8000
                cache-key: xxxxxxxxxxx
            static.mysite.com:
                root-dir: site/django-app/static
                consultant: 8000
                cache-key: yyyyyyyyyyy
            api.mysite.com:
                port: 8000
```

Of course I would need to do some small changes on the `Django` settings, but I know how to handle it. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django Admin pages are generated dynamically. Unfortunately that means that the server can't learn reliably about the assets on those pages and won't be able to use HTTP/2 PUSH to deliver the resources automatically. But  [electric domains](https://www.shimmercat.com/info/articles/structuring-apps/#electric) work well as ordinary static domains. So your second option is correct in principle.

However, with HTTP/2 the cost of using cookies should be low enough (HPACK compression should fold them) that you don't need to use a `www` and `static` domain. You probably are better off by having just one of those domains, say `www`:

```
---
shimmercat-devlove:
    domains:
        www.mysite.com:
            root-dir: site
            consultant: 8000
            cache-key: xxxxxxxxxxx
        api.mysite.com:
            port: 8000
```

This is just your first example! But you need to copy Django's static assets to the `site` folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer @dsign :). It was very useful the details you gave me, and it makes sense. I will test your suggestion, but it should work for sure ;). Thanks again :)

Comment: it worked like a charm :). I'm accepting your response. Thanks a lot mate!